# How can I change the value of a matrix as a specific position

Tags: matlab

Here my original matrix.

```
A =

    60    27    45    72    22    14    56     2     8    39    18    12;
    72    27    60    45    11     7     3    23    41    17    56    39]
```

Then, I want to change position value of `column 1 until 4 in second row` in order that the same value can be arranged in same column.
Here, My desire matrix.

```
Res =

    60    27    45    72    22    14    56     2     8    39    18    12;
    60    27    45    72    11     7     3    23    41    17    56    39]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to post code where you show examples of what you've tried, but I'll point you in the right direction.

You need to first make a direct copy of A in Res, then you can modify this copy so that your slaveRow (the row you want to be overwritten) matches your masterRow (the row you refer to when overwriting the slaveRow).  Like this:

```
A =

60    27    45    72    22    14    56     2     8    39    18    12
72    27    60    45    11     7     3    23    41    17    56    39

columnStart=1;
columnEnd=4;
masterRow=1;
slaveRow=2;
Res=A;
Res(slaveRow,columnStart:columnEnd)=A(masterRow,columnStart:columnEnd);

Res =

60    27    45    72    22    14    56     2     8    39    18    12
60    27    45    72    11     7     3    23    41    17    56    39
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  i=1:2:(1+3*2);
  A(i+1)=A(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Res = A;
 Res(2,[1:4]) = Res(1,[1:4])
```